# Catch2 found by cmake but not accepted due to version mismatch

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2, find-package

I installed *Catch2* on Windows, located in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Catch2/`, but something went wrong when I use `find_package` to use *Catch2*.

In detail, using this cmake file:

```
project(UnitTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(Catch2)
```

And cmake failed with

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Catch2" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Catch2/lib/cmake/Catch2/Catch2Config.cmake, version: 3.3.2 (64bit)
```

---

I tried to use `find_package(Catch2 3)` and `find_package(Catch2 3.3.2)` but they all failed due to version dismatch.

I also tried `find_package(Catch2 "3.3.2 (64bit)")`, but it failed due to invalid call to `find_package`.

I wonder what's happening and how to fix this?

---

Catch2 is installed using something like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:catchorg/Catch2.git
cd Catch2
cmake -Bbuild . -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF
cmake --build build/ --config release --target install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of not accepting the package is in the **parenthesis**: `(64bit)`.

CMake treats your package as **64-bit** one, so that package cannot be used in the project targeting 32-bit platform.

---

Not sure why CMake installs 64-bit Catch project into `C:/Program Files (x86)`. Probably, this is caused by incorrect environment you had when configure Catch (`cmake -Bbuild .`).

Comment: You are right. I found my compile toolchain ar set to be `x86` all the time. When I switch the architecture from `x86` to `amd64`, this Catch2 is accepted and everything works fine.

Comment: The installation guide is copied from Internet and now I found it doesn't match cmake CLI. Later I tried some regular solution: `mkdir build`->`cd build`->`cmake .. -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF`->`cmake --build . --config release --target install`, and Catch2 is still installed in `C:/Program Files (x86)`. Maybe wrong options doesn't matters at all.

Comment: The location of Catch2 seems to be unimportant. I tried to move Catch2 to `C:/Program Files` and cmake also find that package.